# The remote host may not meet vs code server's prerequisites for glibc and libstdc++ vscod

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, server

I was working on the host server. Everything was great till yesterday and today when I start my server, suddenly error occurs in VS code. And my server is not connecting anymore. What should I do? I try everything but nothing works for me. I am attaching the error log for reference.
Here is the error that occurs in the cmd

```
enter code here
[14:54:16.433] Log Level: 2
[14:54:16.435] remote-ssh@0.65.8
[14:54:16.435] win32 x64
[14:54:16.453] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+155.230.28.121", attempt 1
[14:54:16.453] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[14:54:16.453] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[14:54:16.453] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"155.230.28.121":"linux"}
[14:54:16.453] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[14:54:16.453] "remote.SSH.configFile": C:\Users\USER\.ssh\config
[14:54:16.453] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[14:54:16.453] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[14:54:16.453] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[14:54:16.454] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": true
[14:54:16.454] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[14:54:16.454] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[14:54:16.454] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[14:54:16.454] SSH Resolver called for host: 155.230.28.121
[14:54:16.454] Setting up SSH remote "155.230.28.121"
[14:54:16.470] Using commit id "c13f1abb110fc756f9b3a6f16670df9cd9d4cf63" and quality "stable" for server
[14:54:16.472] Install and start server if needed
[14:54:16.473] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[14:54:16.510] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[14:54:16.514] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\USER\.ssh\config"
[14:54:16.514] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 6052 -F "C:\Users\USER\.ssh\config" "155.230.28.121" bash
[14:54:16.515] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[14:54:16.714] > ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[14:54:16.714] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[14:54:16.842] > 3c5b26d3dd63: running
[14:54:16.859] > bash: line 194: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on devi
> ce
> Missing GLIBCXX >= 3.4.18!
> Found versions 3.4.1
> 3.4.2
> 3.4.3
> 3.4.4
> 3.4.5
> 3.4.6
> 3.4.7
> 3.4.8
> 3.4.9
> 3.4.10
> 3.4.11
> 3.4.12
> 3.4.13
> 3.4.14
> 3.4.15
> 3.4.16
> 3.4.17
> 3.4.18
> 3.4.19
> 3.4.20
> 3.4.21
> 3.4.22
> 3.4.23
> 3.4.24
> 3.4.25
> 3c5b26d3dd63$$1$$
> Acquiring lock on /home/farah/.vscode-server/bin/c13f1abb110fc756f9b3a6f16670df9
> cd9d4cf63/vscode-remote-lock.farah.c13f1abb110fc756f9b3a6f16670df9cd9d4cf63     
[14:54:16.872] > 
[14:54:16.879] > Found existing installation at /home/farah/.vscode-server/bin/c13f1abb110fc756f9
> b3a6f16670df9cd9d4cf63...
> Checking /home/farah/.vscode-server/.c13f1abb110fc756f9b3a6f16670df9cd9d4cf63.lo
> g and /home/farah/.vscode-server/.c13f1abb110fc756f9b3a6f16670df9cd9d4cf63.pid f
> or a running server
> Looking for server with pid:
[14:54:16.893] > Starting server with command... /home/farah/.vscode-server/bin/c13f1abb110fc756f
> 9b3a6f16670df9cd9d4cf63/server.sh --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --enable-remot
> e-auto-shutdown  --socket-path=/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1634622855  &>
>  "/home/farah/.vscode-server/.c13f1abb110fc756f9b3a6f16670df9cd9d4cf63.log" < /d
> ev/null
> printenv:
>     SSH_CONNECTION=155.230.29.186 6054 155.230.28.121 23963
>     USER=farah
>     PWD=/home/farah
>     HOME=/home/farah
>     SSH_CLIENT=155.230.29.186 6054 23963
>     MAIL=/var/mail/farah
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     SHLVL=2
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/farah/.vscode-server
>     LOGNAME=farah
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[14:54:16.899] > main: line 488: echo: write error: No space left on device
> main: line 502: echo: write error: No space left on device
> Spawned remote server: 26764
> Waiting for server log...
[14:54:16.912] > 
[14:54:16.936] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:16.970] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.004] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.038] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.071] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.105] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.138] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.172] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.206] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.239] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.273] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.308] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.340] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.374] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.408] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.440] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.474] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.508] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.541] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.576] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.608] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.642] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.676] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.709] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.744] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.776] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.811] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.845] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.878] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.911] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.945] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:17.978] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.012] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.047] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.081] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.113] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.148] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.180] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.214] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.248] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.281] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.319] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.347] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.382] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.416] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.449] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.483] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.516] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.566] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.584] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.617] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.649] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.684] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.716] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.748] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.780] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.813] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.846] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.878] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.910] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.945] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:18.978] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.010] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.044] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.077] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.111] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.145] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.178] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.212] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.246] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.280] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.313] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.347] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.381] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.414] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.447] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.482] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.515] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.548] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.582] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.615] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.649] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.683] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.716] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.749] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.783] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.816] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.850] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.883] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.918] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.951] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:19.986] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.019] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.052] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.086] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.119] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.153] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.186] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.219] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.253] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.286] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.320] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.355] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.387] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.421] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.454] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.488] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.521] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.555] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.590] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.622] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.656] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.690] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.722] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.756] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.789] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.823] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.858] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.912] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.924] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.957] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:20.991] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.026] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.059] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.092] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.125] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.159] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.205] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.226] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.271] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.293] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.335] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.361] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.394] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.429] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.462] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.495] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.528] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.562] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.596] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.630] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.663] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.696] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.730] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.764] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.797] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.835] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.865] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.898] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.932] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.964] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:21.998] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.031] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.063] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.094] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.127] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.160] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.194] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.228] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.261] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.294] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.328] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.361] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.395] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.428] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.462] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.495] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.528] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.562] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.597] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.629] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.662] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.696] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.729] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.763] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.797] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.835] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.865] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.898] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.933] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:22.965] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.003] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.032] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.066] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.100] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.134] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.166] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.199] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.234] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.267] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.300] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.334] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.368] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.402] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.434] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.468] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.502] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.535] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.569] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.602] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.636] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.670] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.703] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.737] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.771] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.804] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.840] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.871] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.905] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.938] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:23.971] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.005] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.039] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.072] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.106] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.139] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.174] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.207] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.241] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.274] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.307] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.341] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.375] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.409] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.442] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.475] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.509] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.544] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.576] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.610] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.645] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.677] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.711] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.744] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.777] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.812] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.852] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.878] > Waiting for server log...
[14:54:24.912] >  
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057) 
> *
> 
> Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /home/farah/.vscode-server
> /.c13f1abb110fc756f9b3a6f16670df9cd9d4cf63.log >>>
[14:54:24.920] > 
> <<< End of server log
> 3c5b26d3dd63: start
> exitCode==32==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==x86_64==
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==8015==
> 3c5b26d3dd63: end
[14:54:24.921] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==8015==

[14:54:24.922] Resolver error: Error: The VS Code Server failed to start
    at Function.ServerInstallError (c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:396975)
    at u (c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:391298)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:395717)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:489314)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:453110
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:456460)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:454189)
    at async c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:526942
[14:54:24.925] ------




[14:54:26.190] "install" terminal command done
[14:54:26.190] Install terminal quit with output: 
[15:16:22.849] Picking SSH host
[15:16:23.949] Selected 155.230.28.121
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly see the image also. Anyone can get an idea about my issue. Thank you

Comment: I have removed the error by deleting data in my docker container. It occurred because my docker container doesn't have enough space due to which it does not connect with the server. Maybe my answer will help someone in the future.   Thank ~

Comment: Does anybody have got a fix on this issue? I cannot remote my server at all.

Comment: @b.john My server show this issue because my docker container was out of memory as I reduce the size of the file and upload it on the container after deleting my previous container it works fine for me.

Answer (score 31):

I had a similar problem today, I got the error **"The container does not meet all the requirements of the VSCode Server"**. Apparently, it's because [in version 1.86 they changed the linux requirements for the remote server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq#_can-i-run-vs-code-server-on-older-linux-distributions)

> Starting with VS Code release 1.86, the minimum requirements for the
> build toolchain of the remote server were raised. The prebuilt servers
> distributed by VS Code are compatible with Linux distributions based
> on glibc 2.28 or later, for example, Debian 10, RHEL 8, Ubuntu 20.04.

My solution was to **downgrade VSCode to version 1.85** with the installer in the link below and disable automatic updates :/

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85

After that, you might need to uninstall and then install again some of the extensions that have been updated, for them to work with the older VS Code version

Comment: I tried this but the Remote SSH extension in vs code says it requires version 1.86 of VS Code. How did u fix that?

Comment: I didn't have that issue, I'm using both SSH and docker remotes without problem in VS Code 1.85

Comment: you can run the older VSCode in portable mode (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) side by side with the latest version.  The link for the older versions zip is: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.85.2/win32-x64-archive/stable.  Just use the older version for when you want to connect to older OS

Comment: For the extensions that are problematic, I solved it by uninstalling and after that reinstalling the extension :)

Comment: after downgrading 1.86 -> 1.85 I had to switch the Remote - SSH extension to  pre-release

Comment: After downgrading VS code 1.86 -> 1.85, you also need downgrading SSH-remote extension

Comment: Fix works nicely for the soon to be EoL CentOS 7 ☠️

Comment: This works! Version 1.85.2 is the version I downgraded to.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same error. VSCode should be able to automatically install the dependent packages like libstdc++. The reason in my case is that there is not enough space on the disk to install libstdc++. Once I freed up some spaces, VSCode can successfully install the packages and connect to the remote.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced same issues as reported above, regarding the error **"The container does not meet all the requirements of the VSCode Server"**.
Upon downgrading my instance of VS code to 1.85 as suggested, I was unable to access the remote-SSH extension, as its only compatible to versions of >1.86. **Here the solution was to use the pre-release version of the SSH remote extension** which worked for me. Will keep an eye on a more permanent fix to this, as I doubt the pre-release version will suffice in the long run.

Comment: How do you install the pre-release version of SSH remote extension?

Comment: @nurasaki, you search for the "remote-ssh" extension plug-in in the search bar; next to the "Install" option you see a drop-down menu; choose "Install pre-release version"

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to switch to SSH FS extension for VSCode.

It helped me in my situation.

No way any admin going to let me upgrade legacy remotes that are untouchable for years.

And using previous versions of VSCode... Well, I think another extension is nice option.

Answer (score 1):

Use pre-release version of Remote-SSH extension. VSCode now supports old earlier OSes with an alert.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did not get that popup, just the same "The remote host may not meet VS Code Server's prerequisites for glibc and libstdc++"