# Could not establish connection to "....": The VS Code server failed to start

Tags: python, vscode-remote

When I try to connect to a remote connection using ssh, I get the pop-up of "The remote host may not meet VS Code server's prerequisite for gibc and libstdc++" and soon I get the below window that connection failed.

[image]
[image]

I am really not sure why this problem started with all the remote systems which I access using Vscode suddenly.
I tried almost everything from the below answer and to my bad luck nothing worked.
[The remote host may not meet vs code server's prerequisites for glibc and libstdc++ vscod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69626028/the-remote-host-may-not-meet-vs-code-servers-prerequisites-for-glibc-and-libstd)
[How to completely uninstall VS Code on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689536/how-to-completely-uninstall-vs-code-on-windows)
Also, there is no way you can delete vscode completely including everything related to ssh connections and install everything fresh.
I tried multiple times uninstalling vscode but the ssh related stuff is not deleted.

It would great if I can be helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a way long time to resolve this issue.
The solution for this problem can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq#_can-i-run-vs-code-server-on-older-linux-distributions).

I followed the below steps and it resolved my problem:

1. Open VS code
2. Uninstall the Remote SSH
3. Go to file => preferences => settings => application => update and change Mode to None.
4. Now, uninstall the latest version 1.86.0
5. Install the older version 1.85.1
6. Go to file => preferences => settings => application => update and change Mode to None.
7. Now install the Remote SSH.

Now, the SSH connection should work.

**NOTE:** How to check version:  Go to Help from top menu, and then click “About”. It will tell you what version of vs code you have.